# Run an Arm cortex M4 with FPU in QEMU

Tags: arm, qemu, fpu

New with qemu here.

Basically I want to emulate a Arm-Cortex-M4F in qemu.

I checked the docus, they say they support 2 boards from TI with M3 cores.

They say they have support for Cortex M4. They say the FPU is active for ARM controllers.

I have managed to use what the internet provides to get it going(tutorials).
I have compiled a c file for M4 (with appropiate compiler flags) and I am running it with this command:

```
qemu-system-arm -M lm3s811evb -m 8K -nographic -kernel notmain.bin
```

And it outputs correctly (to standard output in the console).

Now, here it gets interesting, I have added some Floating point things in the code, converting Celsius to Fahrenheit, added the compiler flag, and the results are visible in the disassembly (fpu instructions).

Running the exact same command as above, I get nothing out.

I suspect it is because of the FPU instructions...cause the M3 core of the board has no FPU module, anyway, here is(are) the question(s).

Is what I am attempting to do in QEMU possible?

If yes, what am I missing?

Comment: First off you would need to use an m4 core not an m3.  On real hardware you would need to enable the floating point coprocessor(s), and then limit the compiler to the subset of fpu instructions supported by the cortex-m4 in thumb mode (single precision only for example).  And then hope that qemu's m4 backend has support for all of that.

Comment: boards are cheap, like $10, you could just get real hardware too.  cortex-m in qemu has been a rocky road, a/the maintainer is/was on SO and has commented on the work done to fix it over the years.  It may be possible to take the stellaris chip emulation but specify the m4 instead of the m3 that was in it.  Or take the sources to qemu and compile it to force the m4 core instead of m3 if that even makes sense, I dont know much about how qemu works in that respect.

Comment: the m3 definitely doesnt have a floating point unit.  in the m4 the floating point unit is optional (in the real world).

Comment: if all you have done is re-compile the C code from m3 code then there is no expectation of success as you have to if nothing else enable the coprocessor as documented by arm.

Comment: guys, the docus say "ARM: FPU emulation support for Cortex-M CPUs, FPU fixes for Cortex-R5F", at least it specifies it has it, how to use it?